# ASP.NET MVC show result without refreshing page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, refresh, viewbag

I did a currency converter. but i have a problem. when i click the calculate the page refreshing and the datas which entered by user is cleaning. i think it is because of using `return View();` :) .How can i solve this problem? Thanks

```
{
    ViewBag.Result = frmAmount;
}
return View();
```

View

```
</p>
<p>
    <label for="text3">Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" name="frmAmount" />
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="text3">Sonuç:@ViewBag.Result</label>
</p>
```

For Example the amount be wiped when button clicked

Comment: Use ``Ajax.BeginFrom`` instead ``Html.BeginForm``

Comment: ViewBag would be empty at the time of button click as it stores the value for just one time at the time of redirecting.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *amount* data is cleaning because when you click on calculate button you are returning the same view again. In order to keep *amount* data you should also pass amount value to the view by ViewBag (`ViewBag.Amount`) or by passing object model into view by using second parameter of `View(viewName, model)`.

In general, I would recommend you to try avoid using ViewBag variables. The preffered method is to use ViewModel instead due to e.g. refactoring. You can read more about it here: [click!](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/12/asp-net-mvc-viewbag-is-bad/)